# Check If Location Value Is Present In Array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, linkedin-api, pdf-parsing

I am writing a script to parse LinkedIn-CV. I am stuck at the work experience section. Currently I am able to extract the work experience text from the PDF. But I have an issue with the location key as it is optional.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Company 1
    [1] => Software Engineer
    [2] => July 2020 - Present  (1 month)   
    [3] => Pretoria, Gauteng, South Africa //this key is optional
    [4] => Company 2
    [5] => CTO
    [6] => September 2016 - Present     (3 years 11 months) 
    [7] => Pretoria, South Africa //this key is optional
)
```

The format is as follows:

- Company Name - Compulsory
- Job Title - Compulsory
- Duration Of Work - Compulsory
- Location - Optional

I tried using `array_chunk($array, 4);` But that only works if the location is present in the array.

My other attempt was to search for the presence of a country in the entire array, but that is tricky as the title of some companies contain countries. like MTN - South Africa.

My last attempt is to try to write a regex to check for the pattern of location. LinkedIn parses it as `City, Province, Country` for South Africa. But for other countries it parses as `City, Country`. But i have not been able to get this correctly. I tried `preg_match('#\((,*?)\)#', $value, $match)` where `$value` is the value of the string for the current iteration

I would like to have an array for each work experience which could either include location or not. For example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Company 1
            [1] => Software Engineer
            [2] => July 2020 - Present  (1 month)   
            [3] => Pretoria, Gauteng, South Africa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Company 2
            [1] => CTO
            [2] => September 2016 - Present     (3 years 11 months) 
            [3] => Pretoria Area, South Africa
        )

)
```

I appreciate your help.

**EDIT:**

Main String (work experience)

```
$string = 'Company 1 Software Engineer July 2020 - Present  (1 month) Pretoria, Gauteng, South Africa Company 2 CTO September 2016 - Present  (3 years 11 months) Pretoria Area, South Africa';

$array = splitNewLine($string);

function splitNewLine($text) {
    $code = preg_replace('/\n$/', '', preg_replace('/^\n/', '', preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "\n", $text)));
    return explode("\n", $code);
}
```

Comment: Is there really no way to have associative array instead?

Comment: @Viney Yes that is possible. But I am confused. How does that help? As I converted from string to array. Do you need me to include the main string?

Comment: Yes it would be helpful to know how exactly you are creating these arrays

Comment: Do the values of the 'Duration' fields always begin with a month?

Comment: @AndrewHardiman yes they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grab lines 4 at a time, then check the location with a proper regular expression, and then adjust the position of the next chunk accordingly:

```
function computeExperiences(array $lines): array
{
  $experiences = [];

  $position = 0;
  while ($chunkLines = array_slice($lines, $position, 4)) {
    $experience = array_slice($chunkLines, 0, 3);
    $locationIsPresent = isset($chunkLines[3]) && preg_match('/\w+,\s\w+(?:,\s\w+)?/', $chunkLines[3]);
    if ($locationIsPresent) {
      $experience[] = $chunkLines[3];
      $position += 4;
    } else {
      $position += 3;
    }
    $experiences[] = $experience;
  }

  return $experiences;
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/L4eln)**

Comment: Hi @Jeto Thanks for the solution. How can i convert the array format I used(numeric) to the format you used?

Comment: Oh no that's not what I meant. The initial version you had worked. The only issue was that your code only returned one work experience and not everything. I guess it is because `$lines` in mine is a numeric array

Comment: @Rotimi It does return all the experiences. I've used your exact format, you can check the demo link right below the sample.

Comment: Hi @Jeto This is my format as per my question `Array
(
    [0] => Company 1
    [1] => Software Engineer
    [2] => July 2020 - Present  (1 month)   
    [3] => Pretoria, Gauteng, South Africa //this key is optional
    [4] => Company 2
    [5] => CTO
    [6] => September 2016 - Present     (3 years 11 months) 
    [7] => Pretoria, South Africa //this key is optional
)` => numeric array

Comment: @Rotimi I've updated the [demo link](https://3v4l.org/L4eln) with your exact data and I've used `print_r` on it. Dunno what else I can do at this point :)

Comment: I see the issue. Your `$lines` is `$data = [
  'Company 1',
  'Software Engineer',
  'July 2020 - Present  (1 month)',
  'Company 2',
  'CTO',
  'September 2016 - Present  (3 years 11 months)',
  'Pretoria, South Africa',
  'Company 3',
  'Webdesigner',
  'Present - Long into the future'
];` and mine is numeric like `[0 => 'Software Engineer']` I'm trying to convert it to your format

Comment: @Rotimi Those are *exactly the same*. If you don't specify indices when declaring an array, PHP will use numerical indices starting from 0, by default. You can define them explicitly if you want, but they'll still be the same.

Comment: Awesome! I was using the wrong variable `$experience` instead of `$experiences`. Thanks alot! I'l upvote this

Comment: Oh, makes sense then. Sorry for getting a bit frustrated, I really didn't understand. Good luck for the rest of your project.

Comment: Oh yeah its fine. The whole CV parsing is new territory to me. Thanks for the help and being patient!